# Convert date to a number?

Tags: date-and-time

Is it possible to convert dates, like e.g.

```
date = "2018-02-15";
```

to be represented by whole number increments starting with 30 December 1899, midnight UTC? I believe this is called DATE format in Windows. Maybe there is an internal Mathematica function that does this?

Comment: hoe about   DateObject[{2018, 02, 15}]

Comment: @J42161217 Sorry, this does not return an integer number of days since 30 December 1899...

Comment: You could simply use [`AbsoluteTime`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTime.html)`[<date>]` or [`DayCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DayCount.html)`["12/30/1899", "02/15/2018"]`

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to avoid the units system would be something like

```
(AbsoluteTime["2018-02-15"] - AbsoluteTime["1899-12-30"])/86400
```

(untested, as I am on *gedanken Mathematica*)

Answer (score 0):

So far I have hacked together the following:

```
QuantityMagnitude[
  DateDifference[{1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0.`}, 
   DateList[ date ]]] // Round
```

> 43146

Can this be made quicker, to be used with large sets of dates efficiently?